# Laravel 5: Add new value in my column migration

Tags: php, laravel-5, database-migration

I have existing table and columns. One of my column named *status* the datatype is enum('0','1') with the default value of 0. And right now I want to add more values in my *status* column. Will look like this enum('0','1','2','3') with also default value of 0.

**My Migration**

```
public function up()
    {
        //
         DB::statement("ALTER TABLE purchase_requisitions CHANGE status ENUM('0', '1', '2','3','4','5')")->default('0')->comment('0 = Unproccessed 1 = Processed');
    }
```

When I migrate this there's an error

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error i
  n your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server v
  ersion for the right syntax to use near '('0', '1', '2','3','4','5')' at li
  ne 1
```

UPDATE:

```
Schema::table('purchase_requisitions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->enum('status')->default('0')->comment('0 = Unproccessed 1 = Processed')->change();
        });
```

Question: How can I implement this using the migration?

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues here. Firstly, your SQL to change the enum values is incorrect. It should be:

```sql
ALTER TABLE purchase_requisitions MODIFY COLUMN status ENUM('0', '1', '2','3','4','5')
```

Secondly, you can't chain method onto the output of `DB::statement`, only on to column declarations. If the comment/default is the same as before, you can just leave the update out. If not, you can do something like:

```php
DB::statement("ALTER TABLE purchase_requisitions MODIFY COLUMN status ENUM('0', '1', '2','3','4','5') DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '0 = Unproccessed 1 = Processed'");
```

Comment: so you're saying is like this? I'll update my post.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you didnt add the new values?

Comment: You need to update your `DB:statement` to run the SQL example i provided, I updated the answer with the full example.

Comment: So everytime I want to add a new value in specific column, I have to use the MODIFY COLUMN? I have a question, what is the purpose of $table->....?

Comment: Yes, laravel doesn't have a helper for modifying enum columns unfortunately.

Comment: `$table` is a reference to the migration builder, so you can use the helpers that laravel provides to build columns rather than writing raw SQL.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197128/discussion-between-angel-and-atymic).

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @atymic, there's some error in his code but I managed to fixed it. It should be like this.

```
Schema::table('purchase_requisitions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        DB::statement("ALTER TABLE purchase_requisitions MODIFY COLUMN status ENUM('0', '1', '2','3','4','5') DEFAULT '0'  COMMENT '0 = Unproccessed 1 = Processed'");
        });
```